# How can we say satyuga is the age of righteousness when tyrants like Hiranyaksh and Hiranyakashyapu tormented people in that same yuga?

Tags: yuga

Hiranyaksh and Hiranyakashyapu tortured people in the satyuga for long time and therefore lord Vishnu had to incarnate as Varaha and Narasimha respectively to kill both of them .

All of this happens in Sat yuga. Imagine how the subjects of those kings felt. They must have felt they're living in horrible age

Comment: I think they ruled somewhere else as Ikshvanku, Pururva (in current Manvantara and Uttanpad, Priyavrata etc. in Svayambhu Manvantra) were ruling Jambudwipa

Comment: Where did you hear they tortured people? I have heard nothing very bad about their reign other than attempting to hurt Prahlada, who was immune to it anyway and even that was reconciled without violence for a really long time.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah Satya Yuga was the age of righteousness but yes some Adharma was done, Bhagawatham says the people suffered much under Hiranyakashipu and Hiranyaksh and after the death of Hiranyaksh Hiranyakashipu became very much angered and he instilled his idol in temples and did a lot of Adharma, priests, sages and people asked MahaVishnu, Then Vishnu said a child named Prahalada will be born when his life gets into mere danger I myself will come and kill Hiranyakashipu, So a few demons in Satyayuga doesn't make the yuga bad

Answer (score 1):

It is because according to Mahabharata, the four legs of dharma were present.

https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m03/m03189.htm

> O bull of the Bharata race, in the Krita age, everything was free from deceit and guile and avarice and covetousness; and morality like a bull was among men, with all the four legs complete.

Answer (score 0):

Well, on the contrary the question maybe reframed, and asked *why the present age is Kaliyuga, when great Saints & Yogis like Sri Ramakrishna Paramhamsa, Swami Vivekananda, Yogananda, etc. have walked on this plane*?

The answer to why the first Yuga is named Satayuga, and the last Yuga is named Kaliyuga, is simple:-

1. Because the scriptures says so.
2. A few evil people, or a few godly people in a certain age (Yuga), just cannot be the sole criterion to determine the Yuga.

Let's see the description of Satyuga in the scriptures, and we shall get the clear answer.

> [Chapter 27](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-skanda-purana/d/doc493337.html), Tīrtha-māhātmya, Nāgara-khaṇḍa, Skanda Purāṇa
>
> [KṚTA YUGA]
>
> Verses 10 to 29
>
> - Kṛta Yuga is said to consist of seventeen lakh twenty-eight thousand years, when Janārdana remains white in colour, and Dharma has
>   all its four feet intact.
> - (Then) the earth is full (in all respects). The people are devoid of lust and anger, fear and hatred. All people are long-lived with
>   quiescent souls and full control over the sense-organs.
> - They are as tall as five Tālas (Palms). They are brilliant and well-informed. Men’s childhood extends to sixteen thousand years.
>   Thereafter the youth extends to thirty-two thousand years. It is only
>   thereafter that old age befalls men slowly. The ultimate life span is
>   one lakh years.
> - In certain cases it extends even beyond that. All living beings, animals, birds and beasts speak the divine language. They are not
>   mutually inimical. Serpents sport about along with mongooses, cats
>   along with mice, deer with lions, and owls with crows. Even without
>   being cultivated, the earth (though not ploughed) produces much
>   vegetation consisting of cereals, pulses, barleys etc. They are tasty
>   and able to accord strength and nourishment. The trees bear fruits in
>   all the seasons with excellent flowers and fruits, good leaves etc.
>   They are devoid of thorns and they resemble Kalpa trees.
> - Cows yield the desired tasty milk at all times. The butter and ghee produced from it is enormous. No woman becomes a widow there, nor an
>   unfortunate wretch. There is no Kākavandhyā (a woman with but one
>   child) there bereft of sons. There is no woman without virtue (all
>   women are virtuous). Birth and death befall men in due order. A father
>   never sees death of his son. People who die do not become ghosts. No
>   one is compelled to stay in Naraka. No one suffers pain due to
>   sickness. All Brāhmaṇas are well-versed in Vedānta. They regularly
>   study their Vedic Mantras. They are delighted in expounding the Vedas
>   and well-versed in the knowledge of Brahman.
> - Kṣatriyas make one of them the king with great devotion and loyalty. They enjoy the earth righteously following his behests.
> - Vaiśyas are engaged in the various activities befitting the Vaiśya community such as breeding of cattle, buying and selling of
>   commodities etc.
> - O most excellent one among Suras, Śūdras are extremely faithful. They do not do anything except service unto Brāhmaṇas and twice-born
>   ones.
> - No one is base-born there nor is there anyone of mixed caste. No impure one and no one of the fifth caste is to be seen there on the
>   earth.
> - Men there perform Yajña (Fire-worship), Yajana (Yajña on behalf of others), Dāna, Vrata, Niyama etc. and pilgrimage without any
>   expectations of personal benefit thereof. O Thousand-eyed One, of this
>   sort is the first Yuga named Kṛtayuga that is conducive to the
>   happiness of all the worlds

So basis the above mentioned divine characteristics found amongst the beings and other forms of existences as a whole, in the age of Satayuga, the first of the Yugas is known as Kṛta Yuga or Satayuga.

Just because few demons or asuras or daityas (/danavas, rakshasa), etc. exists in Satayuga doesn't make it Kaliyuga, just like the presence of godly saints in the Kaliyuga doesn't make it Satayuga.